# PHP value mergin under same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array that I am trying to combine all the sub values that have the same key name and add an extra if there is only 2 with the same key name.

her is a saml example of the array this array hase 92 rows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( 
            [N_127y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 302
                )
        )
    [1] => Array ( 
            [N_127y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 288
                )
        )
    [2] => Array ( 
            [N_144y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 317
                )
        )
    [3] => Array ( 
            [N_144y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 307
                )
        )
    [4] => Array ( 
            [N_144y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 332
                )
        )
)
```

and this is the output I am looking for.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( 
            [N_127y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 302
                    [1] => 288
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
    [1] => Array ( 
            [N_144y4Gral] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 317
                    [1] => 307
                    [2] => 332
                )
        )
)
```

I think i need to use a foreach or for loop to make this happen but i'm not sure on how to structure the function, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there going to be only a single item inside the  `[N_144y4Gral]` array or can be more than one?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam only one

Comment: ok and you want to add a `0` as value for the index where a number of values are less than the other one means `N_127y4Gral` vs `N_144y4Gral`, the question is still not clear as you havent mentioned how many different indexes there could be?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam the array in total has 92 rows with different names each name can appear 1, 2 o 3 times in the array i want to make a new array where the values of each name is sorted in a subarray shown in the example output, and if there is only 1 or 2 with the same name add the missing values as [1] => 0 [2] => 0

Comment: added an answer which does what you want see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop the array and build and associative array, and keep a count of the max of each then you can modify the result array with array fill looping it by reference.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    foreach($sub as $key => $val){
        $res[$key][] = $val[0];
        if(!isset($count[$key])){
            $count[$key] = 1;
        }else{
            $count[$key]++;
        }
    }
}
$max = max($count);
foreach($res as &$subarray){
    $subarray = array_merge($subarray, array_fill(0,$max-count($subarray), 0));
}
var_dump($res);
```

Output from this:

```
array(2) {
  ["N_127y4Gral"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "302"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "288"
    [2]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["N_144y4Gral"]=>
  &array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "317"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "307"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "332"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WHWYg

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $result[$key][] = $val[0];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: this doesn't give me the desired output and how to i go about adding the flouting 0 if there is only 2 with the same key name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` to iterate on each item and extract/copy the values into another array, as you are going to have a single value under the key name, also you want to add a `0` for those indexes where the number of values is less than compared to the other sub-index , you can use `array_pad` for that purpose see below

```
$arr = [
    [
        'N_127y4Gral' => [302]
    ],
    [
        'N_127y4Gral' => [288]
    ],
    [
        'N_144y4Gral' => [317]
    ],
    [
        'N_144y4Gral' => [307]
    ],
    [
        'N_144y4Gral' => [332]
    ]
];

$newArr = [];

//walk array and get the values into another 
//array according to the desired format
array_walk(
    $arr,
    function ($val, $index) use (&$newArr) {
        $newArr[key($val)][] = $val[key($val)][0];
    }
);

//get the array key names
$keys = array_keys($newArr);

//iterate all key names 
foreach ($keys as $key => $keyName) {

    //check the array size if smaller than 3
    if (sizeof($newArr[$keyName]) < 3) {

        //add 0 for the missing indexes
        $newArr[$keyName] = array_pad($newArr[$keyName], 3, 0);
    }
}

print_r($newArr);
```

The above will output the following array

```
Array
(
    [N_127y4Gral] => Array
        (
            [0] => 302
            [1] => 288
            [2] => 0
        )

    [N_144y4Gral] => Array
        (
            [0] => 317
            [1] => 307
            [2] => 332
        )

)
```

Comment: @Andreas yes, there can only be max three not more than that  and any of these 3 misiing indexes we need to put a `0` ,see the comments under the question

Comment: Didn't see that. That should have been in the question and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

check this loop : https://rextester.com/GOGA85799

```
 foreach($old_array as $key=>$value){
       $temp_key="";

       foreach($value as $okey=>$ovalue){
           echo $okey;
           echo $temp_key;
           if($okey!=$temp_key){
               echo "changed";
               $new_array[$okey][]=$ovalue[0];

           }
            $temp_key=$okey;

       }
   }
```